# cv2 : cv2Color()

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to do face detect someone

```
import cv2
import sys

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r"haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:

    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        # cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but everytime I run the program I get this error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-pz4stnv8\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

and there is not a `appveyor` folder in Users even if I show hidden items so I can't reach it.

Comment: Please choose an appropriate title for your question and not just a link to a bibrary function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`video_capture.read()` is not guaranteed to return a valid frame.

`ret` is either True or False depending on whether a frame was read successfully. You should check this value before attempting to further process the frame -- e.g. by adding:

```
if not ret:
    continue
```

The path in the error message is the path to the source code on the machine that was used to build OpenCV, so isn't necessarily the a real path on your machine. That is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

thankss but now ı got this error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-   zsozjuva\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-zsozjuva\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (435) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Comment: and as intelij says it's about the code 'faceCascade'.

Comment: This would suggest that your input to `detectMultiScale` is also empty. Can you try displaying the image after converting it to grayscale in order to confirm that it's valid?

Comment: Ah, or it could perhaps be that your `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` file is missing. Can you confirm that it exists, and try passing the absolute path to the file? For instance:

`faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r"C:\Users\Mirac\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")`

Comment: ohh yes, ı forgot that, and the error has gone thank you so much :)

Comment: Great, glad it's sorted.